# How can get data from a SQL view using SQLSRV PHP 5.3 and IIS7?

Tags: php, sql, view, sqlsrv

#### This is my query

```
    $sqlq= "select * from [reloj].[dbo].[VistaChecador]";

    $t_mov=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlq );
    if( $t_mov === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

    while ($row4=sqlsrv_fetch_array($t_mov, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
        print " $row4[0], $row4[1]";                
    }
    ...
```

This is a SQL view `[reloj].[dbo].[VistaChecador]` and didn't show any result. Before I was MsSql with a PHP 5.2, but I migrate to new server.

If I use this:

```
    $sqlq= "select * from [reloj].[dbo].[EMPLEADOS]";

    $t_mov=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlq );
    if( $t_mov === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

    while ($row4=sqlsrv_fetch_array($t_mov, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
        print " $row4[0], $row4[1]";
    }
```

The Web show me the data, but the table `[reloj].[dbo].[EMPLEADOS]` is not an SQL view. Any pointers of what's I am doing wrong?

Comment: So just to clarify... The first query used to work under PHP 5.2 but no longer works? What version are you using now?

Comment: NO, I have new Server whit ii7 and php 5.3 this versión use SSQLSR for conect to my db sql server ( this not suport the mssql sentences), before use ii6 and php 5.2 and this versión use MSSQL to conect my db. whit mssql in php 5.2 dont have any problem, my problem is whit the sentences SQLQSRV